# systemctl command starting a service won't return on Fedora 22

Tags: fedora

In directory `/lib/systemd/system`, I created a file XYZ.service.
When running `systemctl start XYZ`, it doesn't return. I had to do Ctrl-C to come out the command.  Wonder why.
Interestingly, after I typed Ctrl-C. I can access the service XYZ.

Any idea what I did wrong?  Thanks.

Here is the file XYZ.service

```
[Unit]
Description=XYZ
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/var/www/html/XYZ/ctrler

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I have the same problem (on Ubuntu 15.04).   [Unit]
Description=Start postgresql database

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=postgres
ExecStart=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 14):

Most likely, your command isn't forking, sometimes called daemonizing.  You said `Type=forking` which means that the command is supposed to do a **fork()** and let the parent return when things are set up and the service is up and running.  Your `systemctl` command is waiting for this to happen.

If the command runs without forking, you can tell `systemd` this by setting `Type=simple`.

See the manual page for *systemd.service* for further details on the `Type` configuration.